# Casting Array Result From JavaScript to Something Useful Using ScriptObjectMirror

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, function, nashorn

If I have a JS `function` that returns an array of strings, how should I go about casting it to a useful type (I'm thinking either a Java array or Collection class)? I've noticed that the return type is always a `ScriptObjectMirror` which has an interesting `to(Class<?> clazz)` method, but I'm uncertain on it's use. I've checked several other StackOverflow questions, but none were useful. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok this worked for me:

```
ScriptObjectMirror result = (ScriptObjectMirror) function.invokeFunction("nameGen", 10);
        String[] strings = result.to(String[].class);
```